# For keras layers with unknown sizes is it possible to know the output size for a specific input?

Tags: python, keras, keras-3

We can create a Convolution Neural Network with variable size inputs

```
ip = keras.layers.Input((None, None, 3))
op = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (2, 2))(ip)

model=keras.models.Model(inputs = [ip], outputs = [op])
```

Is there a way to know the size of the output layer op for a specific input?

I know there is a formula to calculate the size for this simple example. Is there a way I can have the model calculate the size for me?

One way I could do that would be to run some sample data through.

```
x = numpy.random.random((1, 64, 64, 3))
y = model(x)
```

Now I can see both of their shapes 1, 64, 64, 3 and 1, 63, 63, 3.

My goal is to be able to use different cnn networks, where I don't know how to calculate the size in general, for example a Resnet101. I have different scale values for the outputs, and I want to be able to scale my ground truth data during training.

Can I get the output size, just from the model and the input data without running a sample through?

Comment: I don't know if keras has a built in function for that, but the output size of a layer is a deterministic function of the input size, kernel size, stride, and padding, so you could compute it for your architecture.

Comment: @Joe I mention that I can calculate it, for this example, but I would like to target the model api so provided my model satisfies the input/output structure I need I can train it.

Comment: oh, I had thought that when you said "I know I can calculate the size, but can also get the size." you meant that you knew you could get the size by 'calculating' the actual output and looking at its size. I didn't realize that you already knew the answer to your question "Can I get the output size, just from the model and the input data, or do I need to run a sample through?" is "Yes, you can get the output size. You do not need to run a sample through."

Comment: @Joe I've tried to make the question more understandable.

Comment: I'd recommend adding the comment you posted to the answer posted, in your post. I had thought that when you wrote "my specific networks", that you had specific networks with specific architectures and only the input size was unknown. I didn't know that your architectures were dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: as @matt mentioned, just calling `model` with a new `Input` is sufficient. No need to create a new model for different inputs. However in this case it is required to keep the respective dimensions unspecified. So this does not work:

```py
import keras_core as keras

ip = keras.layers.Input((10, 10, 3))
op = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (5, 5))(ip)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = [ip], outputs = [op])

model(keras.layers.Input((100, 100, 3)))
```

While this does:

```py
import keras_core as keras

ip = keras.layers.Input((None, None, 3))
op = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (5, 5))(ip)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = [ip], outputs = [op])

model(keras.layers.Input((100, 100, 3)))
```

If you still want a fixed, but different input, you have to implement something along the lines of what I suggested below:

When you use `keras.layers.Input((100, 100, 3))` it actually creates a `KerasTensor` object, which seem to be a lazy / uninitialized tensor object. Passing it recursively trough the other layers via `__call__`, actually modifies the output shape (without computing any flops):

```py
import keras_core as keras

ip = keras.layers.Input((100, 100, 3))
op = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (5, 5))(ip)

print(op)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs = [ip], outputs = [op])
```

Prints:

```
<KerasTensor shape=(None, 96, 96, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_39>
```

The same objects is also available via `model.output`. I guess the solution here is to slightly refactor your code and define a function, that creates the model for a given different input, along the lines of:

```py
import keras_core as keras

def create_model(ip):
    op = keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (5, 5))(ip)
    return keras.models.Model(inputs = [ip], outputs = [op])

model_1 = create_model(keras.layers.Input((10, 10, 3)))
model_2 = create_model(keras.layers.Input((100, 100, 3)))

print(model_1.output)
print(model_2.output)
```

Which prints:

```
[<KerasTensor shape=(None, 6, 6, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_54>]
[<KerasTensor shape=(None, 96, 96, 3), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_56>]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I made my answer based on your answer. If you want to update your answer, then I can accept it. Unless somebody comes along with a better way, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size based on a specific input.

```
inp = keras.layers.Input((64, 64, 3))
y = model(inp)

print(y)
```

Now the output is a defined tensor with a specific shape, I don't think it actually runs the model in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Overall, there is a famous formula for that:

> Output_size = ((Image_size - kernel_size)/(stride_size)) + 1

Of course, when considering padding = "same", things get a little bit complicated:

> Output_size = ((Image_size - kernel_size + 2 * padding_size)/(stride_size)) + 1

where

> padding_size = (kernel_size - 1) / 2

***Just be cautious when using the latter formula. It may sometimes disappoint you.***

Comment: This misses the point. You're talking about a single layer. I'm talking about a model, it might even include a keras application like a resnet101. I'm not going to calculate that on the fly. If I provide dummy input, then the output has a shape. I want the model to tell me it's output shape.